# Partitioning an ordered dataset into N partitions with ~equal sum in spark (maintaining the order while assigning buckets)

Tags: apache-spark, data-partitioning

I have a dataset as below having two columns - Id, UserCount.
The dataset is sorted on Id column in ascending order.

| Id | UserCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 800 |
| 3 | 300 |
| 4 | 400 |
| 5 | 500 |

I want to partition this dataset into n partitions (taking n = 3 for above example) so that the sum of UserCount in each bucket is equal or as close as possible. Something like below table -

| Id | UserCount | BucketId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2 | 800 | 2 |
| 3 | 300 | 2 |
| 4 | 400 | 3 |
| 5 | 500 | 3 |

The constraint here is that I can only take continuous rows into a single bucket, i.e. I can take rows having id = 1 or 1,2 or 1,2,3 or 1,2,3,4 in same bucket. I cannot take rows having id = 1,3 in same bucket without having row having id = 2.

I need to implement this partitioning logic in spark efficiently, any help is much appreciated.

I am thinking of writing a UDAF (if possible with the logic I have) and use dynamic average to decide whether to take next element in the current bucket or not. For instnace if we take mentioned example I would start with bucket 1 and keep on adding elements to it untill the sum of UserCount is less than the expected average bucket size (`Total sum of UserCount` / `Total Bucket` which is 3000/3 = 1000). As soon as the sum of UserCount >= DynamicAverage I will start with the new bucket and calculate the expected average again and continue to do so. I am calling it dynamic average as I will be calculating it at each step and will keep on updating it for each bucket based on the remaing rows and remaining number of buckets.

I am not sure if we can do this even more efficiently in spark so asking for help here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a UDAF with 2 variables for each bucket: list of sums and a list of counts. I'd initialize it with a single element in each list as the first bucket.

When adding a new row to a bucket, I'd compare current sum of UserCount for that bucket to the average UserCount per bucket. If less than the average, add the row to the current bucket. Otherwise, start a new bucket.

Let me know if it works... :-)